# My python script outputs "no coordinates" no matter what keyword I search for using tweepy

Tags: python-3.x, csv, tweepy

The goal is to use python to search for tweets that contain a specified word, grab the lat/long coordinates, and write to a .csv.

UPDATE: At the moment it is returning "no coordinates" no matter what keyword I use.

```
 #All of the consumer keys, tokens, and imports are left out of this sample code. 

file = open("C:\Scripts\Output.csv", "w")
file.write("X,Y\n")

data_list = []
count = 0

class listener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self, data):
    global count

    #How many tweets you want to find, could change to time based
    if count <= 2000:
        json_data = json.loads(data)

        coords = json_data["coordinates"]
        if coords is None:
           print("no coordinates")
        else:
           print(coords["coordinates"])
           lon = coords["coordinates"][0]
           lat = coords["coordinates"][1]

           data_list.append(json_data)

           file.write(str(lon) + ",")
           file.write(str(lat) + "\n")

           count += 1
        return True
    else:
        file.close()
        return False

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
#What you want to search for here
twitterStream.filter(track=["horse"])
```

Expected results would be a CSV file with the latitude and longitude coordinates of tweets with the designated word "horse". UPDATE: It's returning "no coordinates" for whatever keyword I try.

Answer (score 0):

You have a conditional statement for:

```
if coords is not None:
```

However if "coords" is None, there is no catch for your program. I would guess this is where the error lies.

Let me know if this helped! Cheers!

Comment: I added an if else statement for handling no coordinates and it still just runs forever.  I try opening the CSV and it says it's locked, presumably because python is still accessing it. Good suggestion though, I appreciate it.

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: My thoughts would be to add print statements to every other line of your code to see where it actually reaches before it hangs

Comment: I'm using visual studio code and adding breakpoints. Now it's just outputting "no coordinates". I can't tell if it's my script or if it actually can't find any tweets with the word horse in it. Thoughts?

Comment: Well I doubt that it wont find tweets with the word horse in it as this should return at least a few results, is there some way for you to check if your script is correctly scrubbing the tweets?